# Flutter HTTP Plugin

Tags: http, flutter, plugins

This error occurred when I tried to combine an SQL database cloud with Flutter. What might the problem be? I have already installed the HTTP plugin.

```
Running "flutter pub get" in fl_3441...

Error on line 21, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.
 ╷
21 │ ┌ sdk: flutter
22 │ │ http: ^0.12.0
23 │ │
24 │ │ # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
25 │ │ # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
26 │ │ cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
 │ └──^
 ╵
---- Log transcript ----

FINE: Pub 2.8.1
MSG : Resolving dependencies...
SLVR: fact: hello_world is 1.0.0+1
SLVR: derived: hello_world
SLVR: Version solving took 0:00:00.055054 seconds.
 | Tried 1 solutions.
FINE: Resolving dependencies finished (0.1s).
ERR : Error on line 21, column 5 of pubspec.yaml: A dependency may only have one source.
 | ╷
 | 21 │ ┌ sdk: flutter
 | 22 │ │ http: ^0.12.0
 | 23 │ │
 | 24 │ │ # The following adds the Cupertino Icons font to your application.
 | 25 │ │ # Use with the CupertinoIcons class for iOS style icons.
 | 26 │ │ cupertino_icons: ^0.1.2
 | │ └──^
 | ╵
FINE: Exception type: PubspecException
FINE: package:pub/src/pubspec.dart 787:5 Pubspec._error
 | package:pub/src/pubspec.dart 636:11 Pubspec._parseDependencies.<fn>
 | dart:collection MapView.forEach
 | package:pub/src/pubspec.dart 600:15 Pubspec._parseDependencies
 | package:pub/src/pubspec.dart 164:9 Pubspec.dependencies
 | package:pub/src/solver/package_lister.dart 211:35 PackageLister.incompatibilitiesFor
 | ===== asynchronous gap ===========================
 | dart:async Future.catchError
 | package:pub/src/utils.dart 113:52 captureErrors.wrappedCallback
 | package:stack_trace Chain.capture
 | package:pub/src/utils.dart 126:11 captureErrors
 | package:pub/src/command_runner.dart 191:13 PubCommandRunner.runCommand

---- End log transcript ----
pub get failed (65; ---- End log transcript ----)
```

Answer (score 0):

You are not adding packages correctly. Spacing is very important in pubspec.yaml file.

Look at below, new added package must be in line of f of flutter.

```
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  carousel_pro: ^0.0.13
  http: ^0.12.0
```